# Two errors when running ssh in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I try to run this script against a remote machine, to carry out login check, but have some problems executing it with no errors. I have the following error when I run the script:
The Error:

```
bash: -c: option requires an argument
bash: line 2: [: missing `]'
```

The Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh root@192.168.88.20 bash -c '
radtest user password 127.0.0.1 100 testing | grep 'Access-Accept' &> /dev/null
if [ $? == 0]; then
        echo "match"
fi
'
```

Any ideas what could cases the error?
Note: ssh doesn't need a password here.

Comment: You can compress that to: `if radtest user password 127.0.0.1 100 testing | grep -q "Access-Accept"; then ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
if [ $? == 0];
```

should be:

```
if [ $? == 0 ];
```

But as muru suggested it can be:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh root@192.168.88.20 bash -c '"
if radtest user password 127.0.0.1 100 testing | grep -q "Access-Accept"; then
echo "Match"
fi
"'
```

Comment: Invert the quote order, or `$?` will be expanded by the current shell.

Comment: sorry I didn't see that error in question I am going to delete this. Or I'll  try to edit it.

Comment: @taliezin Ok, so the core is working now but still the fist minor error is there: bash: -c: option requires an argument. However, the main functions are working now.

Comment: I edited it. Sorry did not see he first error.

Comment: Much appreciated.